# Continuous time stationary Markov process , $1$ parameter family of operators

Tags: proof-writing, markov-chains

I am currently studying about continious Markov chains. The first question (picture attached), asks to prove that T(0)=I. I want to use the chapman Kolmogorov regularity condition: $P(t)*P(s)=P(s)*P(t)$, but I am realizing that this equation is for transition matrices, and I am not sure I can use it in this exercise?

Does anyone have any clues? Thank you!

Problem:

[image]